# New automatic title links feature (self links only)

Tags: discussion

I asked StackOverflow meta for [bookmarklet to make readable links easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71975/wanted-bookmarklet-for-creating-markdown-links/). We don't have that yet, but apparently we *can* now:

> 2010-11-05: Posting links to the very
>   same site now automatically shows the
>   current title. So, just insert
>   [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/whatever).
>   to become Recent feature changes to
>   Stack Exchange. This is not shown in
>   the preview, but is rendered with the
>   current title upon page load. It does
>   not work for links to other SOFU
>   sites. Trailing punctuation marks such
>   as a comma, dot or question mark
>   (without URL parameters) to get a
>   readable sentence work just fine too.

Answer (score 2):

this is a test, to see if this feature works here on GIS.se too: [New automatic title links feature (self links only)](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/new-automatic-title-links-feature-self-links-only)

Comment: yup, works! yay